# (iOS)How to make Section Horizontal in CollectionView CompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

All examples are made vertically in google.
It is possible to make Section Horizontal in CollectionView CompositionalLayout?
like this...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA8s0.png)
what can I do for this matter?

I looked for the Compositionallayout section but couldn't find it.

Comment: This is the [orthogonalScrollingBehaviour](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199094-orthogonalscrollingbehavior). You have good sample about this in WWDC videos.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963187/horizontally-scrolling-multiple-sections-with-uicollectionviewcompositionallayou

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.